# Multiple, aggregate transforms of web.config

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, web-config, web-config-transform

In short, is it possible to have this kind of nested transformation hierarchy for transorming web.config at build time?

```
web.config
  |_
    web.config.release
        |_web.config.release.live
        |_web.config.release.stage
```

So in other words, web.config.release applies `xdt:transform`s to web.config, and then the last two apply transformations to *the output of that*.

I'm trying to avoid the repetition that I'd otherwise have in all the transforms. The last two in my example here for instance would do little more than insert keys, connection strings or account passwords.

Have I missed something obvious - is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out this sort of works. It does what I want, although I have no idea how it knows which file to use in which circumstance, but given simply these files in VS2013;

[image: files layout]

`web.debug` and `web.release` transforms are applied as normal on build. Seondly, the `Wen.IIS Localhost xxxx` configs are applied to the output of that when published. The latter files only need to contain the few lines that differ from the previous transformation output.

Publishing is good for debug which is what I wanted it for, but for I don't publish live web sites that way. I'd have thought that perhaps there was some build event task in my `csproj` that I could edit but it seems either to be built into VS or defined elsewhere.

So I'm getting the multiple transform task that I wanted, however I haven't found a way to build nested transformations in general as outlined in the question.